# size() command not working when containing method is run within a static method

Tags: java, static, processing, program-entry-point

I don't know what is going on, here is my code:

```
import java.io.*;
File file;
static void main(String[] Args){
  try{
    new MeshViewer().init(Args[0]);
  }catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e){
    new MeshViewer().setup();
  }
}
void init(String file){
  this.file = new File(file);
  setup();
}
void setup(){
  size(500,500);
}
void loop(){

}
```

This program is unfinished, so don't worry about the blank loop() methods, my problem is that size() trows this error:

```
Null Pointer Exception:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at processing.core.PApplet.size(PApplet.java:1587)
    at processing.core.PApplet.size(PApplet.java:1560)
    at MeshViewer.setup(MeshViewer.java:32)
    at MeshViewer.main(MeshViewer.java:24)
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Well what does `PApplet.java` line 1587 use? Fundamentally you haven't given us *nearly* enough information here.

Comment: I don't know, i just know usualy is say `size(width,height);` and it sets the window size, but here it does not work

Comment: maybe you should post some code of your size(...) method, so that we can look where the error occurs?

Comment: i did not create the size method, it is a processing core method, used to set window size

Comment: *"here is my code:"*  That code would not compile, therefore it *cannot* be the code that causes the run-time exception.  For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: @AndrewThompson what do you mean? it is a core processing library method

Comment: Was there some part of *"That code would not compile"*  that you do not understand?   Please be specific - I am not in the mood for '20 questions'.

Comment: please don't reply unless you know what the processing library is

Comment: I know exactly what the processing library is.  ***Your code does not import any of it.***  Most importantly, it does not `extend PApplet` - the likely way that you might get that `size(int,int)` method inherited.

Comment: @AndrewThompson why wouldn't it not compile? it does, the error is a runtime exception, i have tested, if i as `System.out.println("Test")` it outputs `test`

Comment: Processing auto-imports all the core packages.

Comment: `I:\..\MeshViewer.java:16: cannot find symbol
symbol  : method size(int,int)
location: class MeshViewer
    size(500,500);
    ^
1 error`

Comment: sorry, it is not actually in a class, the class meshviewer is implied

Comment: @SuperKael The last 10 comments are about that, we need more details.

Comment: *"Processing auto-imports all the core packages"*  After a couple of years developing Java, you should come back and read that comment.  It will give you a belly laugh, like it just did for me.  :)

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis what do you mean more details? i have only been doing processing for about a year, and java about 2

Comment: *"i have only been doing processing for about a year, and java about 2"*  You have been coding Java for ***2 years*** yet such a simple problem has you stumped?  Time to seek a new profession..

Comment: *"what is so simple?"*  What I just went researching a moment ago for the answer.

Comment: you are confusing me...

Comment: @AndrewThompson Well then, it's been 6 years and I came across this again while browsing my own post history. I was only 13 then, I'm 19 now. Back then, programming was nothing more than a hobby for me, I had been writing java stuff on and off for two years, but it was all very crude. I'm 6 years wiser now, and looking at younger me makes me simultaneously want to laugh and cringe. But it's worth note, the Processing IDE does indeed automatically import its own packages, even if you don't specify it. Processing is pretty much made for newbies like me :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the size() method to resize your window you need a least to declare one. I suggest you replace

```
void setup(){
    size(500,500);
}
```

with

```
void setup(){
    JFrame myFrame = new JFrame();
    myFrame.setSize(500,500);
    myFrame.setVisible(true);      
}
```

Comment: i thought so, but the `line(int, int, int, int)` command and other graphics commands aren't working

Answer (score 2):

The class declaration should be more along the lines of:

```
class MeshView extends PApplet {
```

This means the `MeshView` extends [`PApplet`](http://processing.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/processing/build/javadoc/core/processing/core/PApplet.html), and `PApplet` **inherits** a method `setSize(int,int)` from `java.awt.Component`.

Having done that,

```
void setup(){
    setSize(500,500);
}
```

..should work!

Comment: nicolas solved that already

Comment: Really?  *"..but the `line(int, int, int, int)` command and other graphics commands aren't working"* does not sound very 'fixed' to me!

Comment: but yours does not fix that either

Comment: *"yours does not fix that either"*  So what output do you get?  And what *exact* code is used?  And this time copy/paste them and stop wasting the time of the people trying to help you.

Comment: nvm, i solved it myself...